# Filename exist in os.listdir but os.path.isfile and os.path.exists both fails

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to find file_to_copy in a directory

```
ls = os.listdir(path_to_file)
ls[7]==file_to_copy
```

Which returned True. So we know the file is in the directory path_to_file. I confirmed it again:

```
os.chdir(path_to_file)
file_to_copy in os.listdir('.')
```

Which also returned True.

now if I use the following it'll return False:

```
os.path.exists(file_to_copy)
```

Why can't os.path.exsits find the file while the first two methods can?

Comment: In the last example does `file_to_copy` include the full path?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Nope just the file name like xxx.png

Comment: Notice in the first 2 examples you provide the path. Try `os.path.exists(os.path.join(path_to_file, file_to_copy))`